# Intercept doInsert, doUpdate and doDelete in AX 2012

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

I am currently using event handler subscriptions for database logging within AX2012 on the insert, update and delete methods, however the issue i have incountered is that these events are not being fired if the method is called via a doinsert, doupdate or dodelete, is there a way i can intercept these events?

Answer (score 1):

You could instead override the [aosValidateInsert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xrecord.aosvalidateinsert.aspx), [aosValidateUpdate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xrecord.aosvalidateupdate.aspx) and [aosValidateDelete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xrecord.aosvalidatedelete.aspx) methods. I have included references to the official documentation, sadly it currently does not explain their intended usage.

As the names imply, the methods are called before the actual operation, which may or may not suit your needs.
Remember to return `true`!

Also beware that adding the methods make AX use [record-by-record operations instead of using set operations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa849875.aspx) for example in `delete_from`. Also you cannot disable that using [skipDataMethods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa849875.aspx) (but you can using [skipAOSValidation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xrecord.skipaosvalidation.aspx)).

Answer (score 1):

*doXXXX* methods are used specifically to avoid running any logic associated with this *XXXX* action, so try to intercept them goes against the design pattern of this methods and their utilisation.

Have you tried the standard database logging which you can configure and query by X++ code? For example:

http://www.jaestevan.com/howto-consultar-el-registro-de-base-de-datos-mediante-x